# multiple file download and progress bar update in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, paramiko

I am trying to build one GUI log file downloader tool.

I am trying to download multiple files at the same time using pyqt5 thread worker.

I am using callback(supported by paramiko) function to determine the download percentage. I want to update the progress bar(s) for the particular download at the same time. I am not able to figure out how to pass the progressBar details to a call-back function.
I want to pass "progressBar" to test function(it is a call-back function )

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from configurationFileRead import readConfigFile
import paramiko
import os
from functools import partial


class FileDownload1(QtCore.QThread):
    percentage = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    def __init__(self, fileList, serverList, listProgressBar):
        super().__init__()
        self.fileList = fileList
        self.serverList = serverList
        self.listProgressBar = listProgressBar
    def test(self, size, fileSize):
        sPercentage=((fileSize - size)/fileSize)*100
        if sPercentage != 100:
            sPercentage = 100 - sPercentage
        print(sPercentage)
        
    def _download(self, fileName, serverName, progressBar):
        userId = readConfigFile().getUserId(serverName)
        password = readConfigFile().getPassword(serverName)
        ipAddress = readConfigFile().getIpAddress(serverName)
        logPath = readConfigFile().getLogPath(serverName)
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ipAddress, username=userId, password=password)
        ftp_client=ssh.open_sftp()
        print(str(os.getcwd()))
        try:
            ftp_client.get(logPath+"/"+fileName,str(os.getcwd())+"/"+fileName, callback = lambda s, t : self.percetage.emit(s, t))
        except Excption as e:
            print(e)
        ftp_client.close()
        ssh.close()
    def run(self):
        j = 0
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1) as executor:
            while(j < len(self.fileList)):
                if(self.fileList[j].isChecked()):
                    
                    future= executor.submit(self._download, self.fileList[j].text(), self.serverList[j].text(), self.listProgressBar[j])
                j = j+1
        print("Download END")


class logSearch(QtCore.QThread):
    new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)
    def __init__(self, serverList, serachString, archiveFlg, component):
        super().__init__()
        self.serverList = serverList
        self.searchString = serachString
        self.archiveFlg = archiveFlg
        self.component = component
        self.result = {}
    def fileSearch(self, server, searchText):
        try:

            userId = readConfigFile().getUserId(server.text())
            password = readConfigFile().getPassword(server.text())
            ipAddress = readConfigFile().getIpAddress(server.text())
            logPath = ""

            if(not self.archiveFlg):
                logPath = readConfigFile().getLogPath(server.text())
            else:
                logPath = readConfigFile().getLogArchivePath(server.text())
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(ipAddress, username=userId, password=password)
            if(not self.archiveFlg):
                if self.component == "":
                    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd "+logPath+";for i in *.log\ndo grep -li '"+self.searchString+"' $i\ndone")
                else:
                    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd "+logPath+";for i in "+self.component+"_*.log\ndo grep -li '"+self.searchString+"' \"$i\"\ndone")
                    
            else:
                print(logPath)
                ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd "+logPath+";grep -lri '"+self.searchString+"' .")
            temp1 = ssh_stderr.read()
            print(temp1)
            temp = ssh_stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
            print(temp)
            temp =temp.strip()
            files = list(temp.split("\n"))
            files = list(filter(None,files))
            i = len(files)
            j=0
            tempDict = {}
            while(j < i):
                ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd "+logPath+";ls -l "+files[j])
                temp = ssh_stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
                tempLi = list(temp.split(" "))
                tempLi = list(filter(None,tempLi))
                fileSize = tempLi[4]
                tempFileSize  =  int(fileSize)
                if(tempFileSize < 1024):

                    fileSize = str(round(tempFileSize,2)) + " B"
                else:
                    tempFileSize = tempFileSize/1024
                    if(tempFileSize < 1024):
                        fileSize = str(round(tempFileSize,2)) + " KB"
                    else:
                        tempFileSize = tempFileSize/1024
                        if(tempFileSize < 1024):
                            fileSize = str(round(tempFileSize,2))+ " MB"
                        else:
                            tempFileSize = tempFileSize/1024
                            fileSize = str(round(tempFileSize,2)) + " GB"


                fileDate = str(tempLi[5])+" "+str(tempLi[6])+" "+str(tempLi[7])
                tempLi.clear()
                tempDict[files[j]] = {'Size':fileSize,'Date':fileDate}
                j = j+1
            self.result[server.text()]= tempDict
            ssh.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    def run(self):
        i=len(self.serverList)
        mxW=0
        if(i == 1):
            mxW = 1
        elif(i == 2 or i == 3 or i == 4):
            mxW = 2
        elif(i == 5 or i == 6):
            mxW = 3
        else:
            mxW = 5
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = mxW) as executor:
            j=0
            try:
                while(j < i):
                    future = executor.submit(self.fileSearch, self.serverList[j], self.searchString)
                    j = j+1
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        self.new_signal.emit(self.result)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def _Validate (self):
        validateFlag = True
        if(str(self.searchString.text())== ""):
            self.searchString.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid red;")
            self.searchString.setFocus()
            validateFlag = False
        else:
            self.searchString.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid;")
        if(len(self.serverList.selectedItems())) == 0:
            self.serverList.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid red;")
            validateFlag = False
        elif len(self.serverList.selectedItems()) > 8:
            self.selectedServer.setText("You can only Choose Upto 8 Server")
            self.selectedServer.setStyleSheet("color:blue;font:Bold")
            self.serverList.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid red;")
            validateFlag = False
        elif len(self.serverList.selectedItems()) > 1 and self.specificFileFlag.isChecked() == True:
            self.selectedServer.setText("Select only one Server")
            self.selectedServer.setStyleSheet("color:red;font:Bold")
            validateFlag = False
        else:
            self.serverList.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid;")
        if(validateFlag):
            self.downloadSelected.setDisabled(True)
            i=len(self.listProgressBar)
            n=0
            while(i > 0):
                self.listProgressBar[n].deleteLater()
                self.listCheckBox[n].deleteLater()
                self.listDateLabel[n].deleteLater()
                self.listSizeLabel[n].deleteLater()
                self.listServerLabel[n].deleteLater()
                i = i-1;
                n=n+1
            self.listProgressBar.clear()
            self.listCheckBox.clear()
            self.listDateLabel.clear()
            self.listSizeLabel.clear()
            self.listServerLabel.clear()
            self.submit.setDisabled(True)
            self.errorLabel.setText("Search Started...")
            self.logSearch = logSearch(self.serverList.selectedItems(), self.searchString.text(), self.searchArchive.isChecked(), self.comonentComboBox.currentText())
            self.logSearch.new_signal.connect(self.printResult)
            self.logSearch.start()
    def printResult(self, result):
        self.errorLabel.setText("Search Completed")
        serverList = list(result.keys())
        print(result)
        l = len(serverList)
        k=0
        m = 0
        i = 0
        while(i < l):
            logNameList = list(result[serverList[i]].keys())
            n= len(logNameList)
            j=0
            while(j < n):
                self.listCheckBox.append(QtWidgets.QCheckBox())
                self.listSizeLabel.append(QtWidgets.QLabel(result[serverList[i]][logNameList[j]]['Size']))
                self.listDateLabel.append(QtWidgets.QLabel(result[serverList[i]][logNameList[j]]['Date']))
                self.listCheckBox[m].setText(logNameList[j])
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listCheckBox[m], m, 0)
                self.listServerLabel.append(QtWidgets.QLabel())
                self.listServerLabel[m].setText(serverList[i])
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listServerLabel[m], m, 1)
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listSizeLabel[m], m, 2)
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listDateLabel[m], m, 3)
                self.listProgressBar.append(QtWidgets.QProgressBar())
                self.listProgressBar[m].setValue(0)
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.listProgressBar[m], m, 4)
                j = j+1
                m=m+1
            i = i+1
        self.submit.setDisabled(False)
        self.downloadSelected.setDisabled(False)
    def hello122(self):
        print("invoked")
    def _FileDownload(self):
        self.test = FileDownload1(self.listCheckBox, self.listServerLabel, self.listProgressBar)
        self.test.percentage.connect(self.hello122)
        self.test.start()
    def _ArchiveFlag(self):
        if (self.searchArchive.isChecked()):
            self.autoDownload.setChecked(True)
            self.autoDownload.setDisabled(True)
        else:
            self.autoDownload.setDisabled(False)
    def _FileDownloadFlag(self):
        if(self.specificFileFlag.isChecked()):
            self.label.setText("<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#000000;\">File Name</span><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;\">*</span></p></body></html>")
            self.submit.setText("Download File")
            self.autoDownload.setChecked(False)
            self.autoDownload.setDisabled(True)
            self.searchArchive.setDisabled(True)
            self.comonentComboBox.hide()
            self.downloadSelected.setDisabled(True)
        else:
             self.label.setText("<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#000000;\">Search String</span><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;\">*</span></p></body></html>")
             self.submit.setText("Search")
             self.comonentComboBox.show()
             self.autoDownload.setDisabled(False)
             self.searchArchive.setDisabled(False)
    def _serverList(self):
            if len(self.serverList.selectedItems()) > 8 :
                self.selectedServer.setText("You can only Choose Upto 8 Server")
                self.selectedServer.setStyleSheet("color:red;font:Bold")
            elif len(self.serverList.selectedItems()) > 1 and self.specificFileFlag.isChecked() == True:
                self.selectedServer.setText("Select only one Server")
                self.selectedServer.setStyleSheet("color:red;font:Bold")
            elif len(self.serverList.selectedItems()) == 0:
                self.selectedServer.setText("")
            else:
                self.selectedServer.setText(str([item.text() for item in self.serverList.selectedItems()]))
                self.selectedServer.setStyleSheet("color:black;font:regular")
                self.serverList.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid;")


    def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(823, 588)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 761, 60))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.searchString = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.searchString.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(673, 16777215))
        self.searchString.setObjectName("searchString")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.searchString, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.submit.setObjectName("submit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.submit, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.componentLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.componentLabel.setObjectName("componentLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.componentLabel, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.comonentComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.comonentComboBox.setObjectName("comonentComboBox")
        self.comonentComboBox.addItem("")
        lengthOfComponent = len(readConfigFile().getComponentList())
        m=0
        while(m < lengthOfComponent):
            self.comonentComboBox.addItem(readConfigFile().getComponentList()[m])
            m = m+1
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comonentComboBox, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.errorLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 751, 16))
        self.errorLabel.setText("")
        self.errorLabel.setObjectName("errorLabel")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 361, 151))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.serverList = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.serverList.setEnabled(True)
        self.serverList.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 331, 121))
        self.serverList.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.serverList.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Fixed)
        self.serverList.setObjectName("serverList")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        lengthOfServers = len(readConfigFile().getServerList())
        k=0
        while( k < lengthOfServers):
            if readConfigFile().getServerList()[k] != "Component":
                self.serverList.addItem(readConfigFile().getServerList()[k])
            k = k+1
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 140, 361, 151))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.autoDownload = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.autoDownload.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 121, 20))
        self.autoDownload.setObjectName("autoDownload")
        self.specificFileFlag = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.specificFileFlag.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 171, 20))
        self.specificFileFlag.setObjectName("specificFileFlag")
        self.downloadSelected = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.downloadSelected.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 97, 141, 31))
        self.downloadSelected.setObjectName("downloadSelected")
        self.searchArchive = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.searchArchive.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 141, 20))
        self.searchArchive.setObjectName("searchArchive")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 191, 21))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 540, 161, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.selectedServer = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.selectedServer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 751, 21))
        self.selectedServer.setText("")
        self.selectedServer.setObjectName("selectedServer")
        self.serverList.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self._serverList)
        self.submit.clicked.connect(self._Validate)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 310, 731, 211))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 727, 207))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.listCheckBox = []
        self.listProgressBar = []
        self.listServerLabel = []
        self.listSizeLabel = []
        self.listDateLabel = []
        self.searchArchive.toggled.connect(self._ArchiveFlag)
        self.specificFileFlag.toggled.connect(self._FileDownloadFlag)
        self.downloadSelected.clicked.connect(self._FileDownload)
        self.downloadSelected.setDisabled(True)
        self.checkBox.setDisabled(True)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#000000;\">Search String</span><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;\">*</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.submit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Server List"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.serverList.isSortingEnabled()
        self.serverList.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.serverList.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Other Configuration"))
        self.autoDownload.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.autoDownload.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto Download"))
        self.specificFileFlag.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>write the file name in &quot;Search String&quot; and Click on Search Button</p></body></html>"))
        self.specificFileFlag.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Download Specific file"))
        self.downloadSelected.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Download Selected"))
        self.searchArchive.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search in Archive"))
        self.checkBox.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>This option will try to compress the file in server before downloading</p></body></html>"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Compress Before Download"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#969696;\">Created by - Sudipto Khan</span></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's available as `self.listProgressBar`, isn't it?

Comment: no that is list of progress bar [progress bar 1, progress bar 2, ..]
i am sending one by one to the executor.
future= executor.submit(self._download, self.fileList[j].text(), self.serverList[j].text(), self.listProgressBar[j])
_download - in this function i am downloading the file and also calling the call-back function. please also suggest if the design in wrong.
   in this function i am passing single progress bar details which needs to be update only for that file. variable name : progressBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access GUI elements outside the main Qt thread, so you have to send the address list to the QThread and use a custom signal to notify the progess, then in the main thread you can use the addresses as references to each address bar.

I'm assuming you're probably using a QTableWidget, so the following example works with the first column for the server name, the second for the file name, and the third to show the QProgressBar (added using [`setCellWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)).

```
FileDownload1(QtCore.QThread):
    percentage = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str, int)
    def __init__(self, urlData):
        super().__init__()
        self.urlData = urlData

    def _download(self, fileName, serverName):
        # ...
        try:
            ftp_client.get(
                logPath+"/"+fileName, 
                str(os.getcwd())+"/"+fileName, 
                callback = lambda s, t: self.percentage.emit(server, path, int(s / t * 100)))
        # ...

    def run(self):
        j = 0
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1) as executor:
            for serverName, fileName in self.urlData:
                future = executor.submit(self._download, serverName, fileName)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def startDownload(self):
        urlData = []
        self.progressBars = {}
        for row in range(self.fileTable.rowCount()):
            serverName = self.fileTable.item(row, 0).text()
            fileName = self.fileTable.item(row, 1).text()
            urlData.append((serverName, fileName))
            progressBar = self.fileTable.cellWidget(row, 2)
            self.progressBars[(serverName, fileName)] = progressBar
        self.downloader = FileDownload1(urlData)
        self.downloader.percentage.connect(self.percentageUpdate)
        self.downloader.start()

    def percentageUpdate(self, serverName, fileName, percentage):
        self.progressBars[(serverName, fileName)].setValue(percentage)
```

Comment: i tried to replace the call back function with lambda file is not full file is not getting downloaded. for me the file size is 28 MB. but it is downloading only 32 KB. any idea?

Comment: i have updated the full code for your reference. please help. thank you

Comment: @sudiptokhan your updated code is too complex to read, also you are clearly editing a file generated by `pyuic`, which is something that should **never** be done. I strongly suggest you to read and study my answer, then recreate your whole script according to the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), and then start from there.

Comment: hi issue fixed. thank you. with your solution it worked. thank you so much